# Javascript - How to insert an element from a specific index to the end of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Each of the element in my list has an Array to hold comments, such as

```
for (let i = 0; i < myList; i ++) {
    myList[i][‘comments’] = [];
}
```

My failed attempt:

```
if (someCondition) {
    // insert from index k to the end of the array
    myList[‘comments’].splice(k, 0, “newElement”);
}
```

An example:

```
myList = [ “comments”: [“1, 2”], “comments”:[], “comment”: [“2”, “2”], “comment”: [] ]
```

Goal: 
Insert from index 2

```
myList = [ “comments”: [“1, 2”], “comments”:[], “comment”: [“2”, “2”, “newElement"], “comment”: [“newElement”] ]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does "insert from" mean that you move the element or that you copy the element? So if you have an array `a = ["a","b","c","d"]` then would "inserting from" index 1 leave you with `["a","c","d","b"]` or `["a","b","c","d","b"]`?

Comment: I think the OP wants `myList['comments'].push(myList['comments'].splice(k, 1)[0])`

Comment: @JJJ Added example above

Comment: @mhodges Added example above

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. So what you actually want is to add a *new* element to two places...?

Comment: Yes from index 2 to the end of the array.

Comment: `myList` isn't even  valid structure. Provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

array.push("string"); will push an element to the end of the array.

array.splice(k,1); will delete the item with key=k from the array.

You could do something like:

```
array.push(array[k]);
array.splice(k,1);
```

Comment: Alternatively: `array.push(...array.splice(k, 1));` or `array.push(array.splice(k, 1)[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

To add an element to your array you can use the spread operator.

```
let myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4];
myArray = [ ...myArray, 5 ]; // This will add 5 to your array in the very last
```

Or if you prefer to add it in the first position in your array you can simply do something like this.

```
myArray = [ 55, ...myArray]; // Will add 55 as the first index in your array
```

To remove an element from the array you can use `Array.filter` method. Which is as follows;

```
myArray = myArray.filter(val => val !== 5); // This will remove 5 element from your array.
```